# Where do I find Google.Apis.Contacts.v3 for .NET?

Tags: contacts, google-contacts-api

There is a lot of different Google API dlls for .NET, for example Google.Apis.Calendar.v3. But nothing for Contacts API.
Using older versions or other approaches is not a solution because I already use v3 of several APIs. I need to add a Contacts API.

Answer (score 4):

The Contacts API v3 is supported by the the [.NET library for the Google Data API](https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/):

https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fclients%2Fcs%2Fsrc%2Fgcontacts

To learn more about its usage, please check the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/

Comment: Well, these are all links that I know. GData uses a different approach to authorization. How can I make it work with OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient> and AuthorizationState?

Comment: Those classes are part of another library. If you want to use OAuth 2.0 check this sample: https://code.google.com/p/google-gdata/source/browse/trunk/clients/cs/samples/oauth2_sample/oauth2demo.cs

Comment: Why does that download still say version 2.2 if it's supposed to support version 3?

Comment: The Google GData Contacts nuget package can be found here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.GData.Contacts